# VeeValidate check for errors in entire scope

Tags: vue.js, jsx, vee-validate

I am trying to render out a warning if there is an error within a specific scope. This is due to the form being across multiple tabs and hopefully making it easier for people to see what needs fixing.

The issue is, I have tried multiple methods but they are not working. This is the current method:

```
const TabInternals = Vue.component('TabInternals', {
    props: {
        title: String,
        scope: String
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <i v-show={this.errors.any(`${this.scope}.*`)} class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>{` ${this.title}`}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `this.errors` available in this component? Or you need to pass that as `props` as well?

Comment: @ljubadr it is available in the component. I believe it's automatically carried over. Out of curiosity i did try and pass this.errors down but it had no effect.

Comment: Try this [github issue](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/835#issuecomment-330333219).

Comment: code is now as follows but didn't work:

const TabInternals = Vue.component('TabInternals', {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    props: {
        title: String,
        scope: String
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <i v-show={this.errors.any(`${this.scope}.*`)} class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>{` ${this.title}`}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

Comment: maybe try `<i v-show="this.errors.any()" ...`

Comment: Also `v-show="..."` instead of `v-show={..}`

Comment: Yeah that's returning false even though there is an error. I also checked Vue devtools and this.errors is in the component with one item in the error array. So the error is getting to the component with both scope and name registered. It's just not doing something after the fact.

Comment: @ljubadr this is written in JSX so has to have {} instead of "" :)

Comment: Ah, I'm too tired, I missed JSX :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, each component gets its own instance of a vee validator (and therefore errors too). If you want to access errors from a different scope, you will need to use inject to pass the parent validator instance to the child components so that they share a validator instance:

```
export default {
  inject:[ '$validator'],
  // ...
};
```

ref - https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/1774